# Can't center the title of my webpage

Tags: html, css

[image: https://scontent-a-lhr.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/l/t31.0-8/10604426_723944574340963_659623887187792162_o.jpg]

I have been struggling with this for the last 2 hours, and I can't fix this....

I want to center the text of the title with a reference the actual page, with the faculty symbol just staying fixed on the left.

I'm sorry if this post is repeated, but i've google by over 100 posts, and not found a solution i could break through... needless to say, I'm still very much noob to html and css

HTML:

```
<header>
  <a href ="index.html" id ="logo">
    <a href="http://ist.utl.pt"><img src="IMG/IST.png" alt="IST Logo" class="IST-icon"></a>
  </a>
  <h1> Titulo do Blog </h1>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="about.php"  <?php if ( isset($section) && $section == "index")   {} ?> >About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.php"  <?php if ( isset($section) && $section == "about")   {} ?> >QQL Coisa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Contacts.php" <?php if ( isset($section) && $section == "Contactos") {} ?> >Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header{  margin: 0 0 20px 0; padding: 5px 0 0 0; width: 100%; }

#logo {text-align: center;  margin: 0; }
.IST-icon {float: left; width: 200px;  margin: 5px 0; }

h1{ float: left; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;  font-size: 1.75em; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1em; }
```

Comment: Is `position: absolute` a possibility? Would need a fixed height header... Or add 200px `padding-right` to the header, to offset the left logo.

Comment: i tried to do so, but it still only relates with the remaining space left from the image, making the image uncentered to all but the resolution i trim it to.

Comment: you have an a tag nested within another a tag.

Comment: what about it? how can i fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can offset the left logo margin (200px) on the right with a padding on the H1 element.

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/0zhw40xx/

```
header {  
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
header:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
#logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.IST-icon {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
h1 { 
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1em;
    background: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 200px;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
nav * {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I added:

- background colors
- clearfix on header, because a float
- display inline for nav items
- padding-right on H1

Now I'm starting to doubt this is what you mean... I thought the problem was with getting the H1 correctly centered. True?

Comment: you got my objective right. Lot's of replies, im trying them all! :D thanks,

Comment: this one does what i wanted,thanks! Now off to learn how to vertically allign stuff

Comment: [Vertical centering is impossible in CSS lol!](https://jsbin.com/honawo/quiet/) by @jaffathecake

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the types of "display" and what "float" does with elements.

1. remove the `float` from the `h1` element
2. add `display: inline;` to it
3. put an `text-align: center;` on the parent `header` element

Futher reading:

All about floats: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Difference block and inline: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

Comment: i "think" the parent element already contains text-align.... namely the #logo.

i tried to add text-align and its still not centered :/

i have "some" awereness of what float does to elements, and i know what is causing the problem... but i can't fix it

Comment: The header was meant with the parent element in this case - float does take elements out of the document float - its like they are in "free space" and have no relation to other elements - well, learn CSS my friend :-)

Comment: i'm working on it, thanks for the explanation, every little help counts :D

Comment: Just added two links, I think it is way better you understand how CSS elements behave instead of giving you a solution! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<a href ="index.html" id ="logo">
            <a href="http://ist.utl.pt"><img src="IMG/IST.png" alt="IST Logo" class="IST-icon"></a>             </a>
            <h1> Titulo do Blog </h1>
```

To:

```
<h1>
    <a href="http://ist.utl.pt"><img src="IMG/IST.png" alt="IST Logo"></a>
    <a href="index.html">Titulo do Blog</a>
</h1>
```

You can't nest two `a` elements.

There's also no need to float the `img` to the left as images are by default inline and behave accordingly. Just set `header h1` to `text-align: center` and you're good.

Comment: isn't

<a href ="index.html" id ="logo"></a>
<a href="http://ist.utl.pt"><img src="IMG/IST.png" alt="IST Logo" class="IST-icon"></a> 
<h1> Titulo do Blog </h1>

better? for some reason if i replace your code directly my entire website goes haywire.

Comment: Nesting two `a` elements is not only worse, it's not even valid code. Which link do you expect the browser to navigate to on click?

Comment: After you've changed your HTML you also need to update the CSS to reflect those changes tho. That's probably why it looks weird.